# Jump forward in andengine Android

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a Game in which sprite have to jump forward .
I already explore it and used MoveYModifier for up and then MoveYModifier for down again it is working right except on more then one tap on the screen.But I want to move him forward as well while jump.

```
                 final Entity playerEntity = move;
                 final float jumpDuration = 3;
                final float startX = playerEntity.getX();
                final float jumpHeight = 100;

                final MoveXModifier moveUpModifier = new MoveXModifier(jumpDuration / 2, startX, startX - jumpHeight); // - since we want the sprite to go up.
                final MoveXModifier moveDownModifier = new MoveXModifier(jumpDuration / 2,startX - jumpHeight, startX);
                final SequenceEntityModifier modifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(moveUpModifier, moveDownModifier);

                playerEntity.registerEntityModifier(modifier);
                return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using MoveXModifier why not just use the MoveModifier?
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/modifier/MoveModifier.java

```
final MoveModifier jumpForward = new MoveModifier(pDuration, pFromX, pToX, pFromY, pToY);
```